# Controlling bandwidth on a Windows 2003 VPS server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, bandwidth, bandwidth-control

We were dinged recently by our ISP when our server briefly saturated their line.  Apparently they don't like bursty traffic.  Who knew?  Like many low cost hosts, they specify limits in terms of total monthly bandwidth, but they also 'reserve the right' to terminate network access for going over other unspecified limits, under the guise of protecting their customers.

I'm looking at modifying Apache mod_cband, but if that doesn't work, or isn't possible for whatever reason:

- What other programs/utilities can I install on a Windows 2003 virtual private server that allow me to control the bandwidth, both incoming and outgoing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking one of the products from [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com) or [BandwidthController](http://www.bandwidthcontroller.com) might fit the bill.